# mysql query select multiple joins -> distinct

Tags: mysql, distinct

I have a table with customers, phone numbers and fax numbers.
Customers can have multiple phone numbers and fax numbers.
When I select the customers data with

```
SELECT customer.FirstName, customer.Id, phone.Phonenumber, fax.Faxnumber
FROM customer
LEFT JOIN phone ON customer.Id = phone.CustomerId
LEFT JOIN fax ON customer.Id = fax.CustomerId
WHERE customer.Id =7
LIMIT 0 , 30
```

I get 4 rows back since this customer has 2 phone numbers and 2 fax numbers

```
FirstName   Id  Phonenumber     Faxnumber
Wim         7   090-123-1248    093-123-1234
Wim         7   090-123-1248    093-123-1235
Wim         7   090-123-1249    093-123-1234
Wim         7   090-123-1249    093-123-1235
```

Is there some way to only get the phone numbers and fax numbers once ?
like this

```
FirstName   Id  Phonenumber     Faxnumber
Wim         7   090-123-1248    093-123-1234
Wim         7   090-123-1249    093-123-1235
```

I have been reading up on DISTINCT but did not find the solution.

Comment: please create sqlFiddle. So we can understand easily.

Comment: There is no way, because your phone number and fax number are unique by combination. if phone number on row 2 & row 3 exchanges, you could get your result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try `GROUP_CONCAT` with `distinct`.

```
SELECT 
  customer.FirstName, 
  customer.Id, 
  GROUP_CONCAT(distinct phone.Phonenumber), 
  GROUP_CONCAT(distinct fax.Faxnumber)
FROM customer
LEFT JOIN phone ON customer.Id = phone.CustomerId
LEFT JOIN fax ON customer.Id = fax.CustomerId
WHERE customer.Id = 7
GROUP BY customer.id
LIMIT 0 , 30
```

It will give you something like:

```
FirstName   Id  Phonenumber                  Faxnumber
Wim         7   090-123-1248,090-123-1249    093-123-1234,093-123-1235
```

Then you could explode Phonenumber and Faxnumber to an array in your program easily.

Comment: Very nice! And yes, I think the extended answer is that some app logic must be done to parse the rows no matter what. Either using your sample with explode, or the original query with grouping at app-level.

Comment: Thank you. I will have to solve this on the application level and not on the database level. As it is now I think it will be better to solve this problem by running multiple queries because there is more data to be retrieved from the phone column (kind of phone: mobile, office, home)
I was just wondering if it would be possible to not show any row that has any identical information using SQL only.

Answer (score 0):

you could do it but it isn't very pretty like the GROUP_CONCAT answer.
[sqlFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/66e321/2/0)

```
SELECT customer.FirstName, customer.Id, p.Phonenumber, f.Faxnumber
FROM customer
LEFT JOIN (SELECT phoneNumber,
                  customerId,
                  IF (@prevCustomer != customerId,@row:=1,@row:=@row+1)
                  as row,
                  @prevCustomer := customerId
           FROM phone,(SELECT @row:=0,@prevCustomer:=0)r
           ORDER BY customerId)as p
ON customer.Id = p.CustomerId
LEFT JOIN (SELECT faxNumber,
                  customerId,
                  IF (@prevCustomer != customerId,@row:=1,@row:=@row+1)
                  as row,
                  @prevCustomer := customerId
           FROM fax,(SELECT @row:=0,@prevCustomer:=0)r
           ORDER BY customerId)f 
ON customer.Id = f.CustomerId
AND (p.row = f.row OR p.row IS NULL)
WHERE customer.Id = 7
LIMIT 0 , 30
```

it works for cases where there are equal or more phone numbers than fax numbers. If you have more fax numbers then phone numbers the extra fax numbers won't get shown. So I suggest you use the `GROUP_CONCAT` answer. It's safer.

Answer (score -3):

you can add "group by" to grouping your phone row, so your SQL like this

```
SELECT customer.FirstName, customer.Id, phone.Phonenumber, fax.Faxnumber
FROM customer
LEFT JOIN phone ON customer.Id = phone.CustomerId
LEFT JOIN fax ON customer.Id = fax.CustomerId
WHERE customer.Id =7
GROUP BY phone.Phonenumber,fax.Faxnumber
LIMIT 0 , 30
```

Comment: Group by the 2 fields would give him the same result, because there are 4 unique combinations on the 2 fields: 1248/1234, 1248/1235, 1249/1234, 1249/1235 . The duplicates remain.